# How to make the next 3 images appear in carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I am trying to make my slider slide to the next 3 slides in my carousel.How it should work is the first 3 images should show, and then when you click the next arrow the next 3 images should show.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Basically the opacity of the last 3 pictures should be 0 until you click next then the opacity becomes 1 for the next 3 pictures.

This is what I have done so far:

HTML:

```
 <section>
        <div class="immigration-service">
          <h1>Cross-border financial and immigration services</h1>
          <div class="carousel">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <img
                  class="slide"
                  src="images/British citizenship and Immigration.jpg"
                  alt="British citizenship and Immigration Image"
                />
              </li>
              <li>
                <img
                  class="slide"
                  src="images/Australian Migration.jpg"
                  alt="Australian Migration Image"
                />
              </li>
              <li>
                <img
                  class="slide"
                  src="images/Citizenship by investment.jpg"
                  alt="Citizenship by investment Image"
                />
              </li>
              <li>
                <img
                  class="slide-2"
                  src="images/British citizenship and Immigration.jpg"
                  alt="British citizenship and Immigration Image"
                />
              </li>
              <li>
                <img
                  class="slide-2"
                  src="images/Australian Migration.jpg"
                  alt="Australian Migration Image"
                />
              </li>
              <li>
                <img
                  class="slide-2"
                  src="images/Citizenship by investment.jpg"
                  alt="Citizenship by investment Image"
                />
              </li>
            </ul>

            <button class="button prev" data-carousel-button="prev">
              &#60;
            </button>
            <button class="button next" data-carousel-button="next">
              &#62;
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

CSS:

```
.immigration-service
{
  margin-top: 34vh;
}

.immigration-service h1
{
  padding-top: 113px;
  text-align: center;
}

.immigration-service ul 
{
  display: flex;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.immigration-service li
{
  display: block;
 list-style-type: none;
}

.button {
  display: flex; 
  font-size: 60px;
  align-items: center; justify-content: center;
  color: #115577;
  width: 30px; 
  height: 50px;
  border: 0px;
}
button.prev {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0;  
  top: 106vw;
}
button.next {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 55vw;
  top: 106vw;

}
```

Javascript:

```
let images = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
let index = 0;
window.show = function(increase) {
  index = index + increase;
  index = Math.min(Math.max(index,0), images.length-1);
  images[index].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

Comment: Where's your code for the button actions?

Comment: Hello @Phaelaxz, I am not sure what you mean, it is in te HTML section ```<button class="button prev" data-carousel-button="prev">
              &#60;
            </button>
            <button class="button next" data-carousel-button="next">
              &#62;
            </button>```

Comment: I think what @Phaelaxz is asking is please show us how you add an event listener to the buttons and show us what action is taken then (when the user clicks). This link should help you put a runnable snippet into your question so we can see the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am not sure how to go about that part